# what is the best and efficient way to call functions of an already deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, interfaces

if I want to call a function of an already deployed contract for example an ERC20 token which one is the best and efficient way to call it's functions?
using call method

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = add.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("foo(string,uint256)", "call foo", 123)
```

or using interface

```
IFACE contract = IFACE(add)
contract.foo("call foo", 123)
```

or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the contract with the interface is the best option because it provides type safety.

In terms of gas efficiency, they both are almost the same.

Check the following test contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

interface IFACE {
  function foo(string memory s, uint256 n) external;
}

contract MyContract is IFACE {
  function foo(string memory s, uint256 n) external {
    // do something with s and n
  }
}

contract Contract {

  address public myContractAddress;

  constructor(address _myContractAddress) {
    myContractAddress = _myContractAddress;
  }

  function test1() public {
    IFACE(myContractAddress).foo("etc", 1);
  }

  function test2() public {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = myContractAddress.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("foo(string,uint256)", "etc", 123));
    //...
  }

}
```

Notice the `test1` and `test2` functions.

`test1` function uses the interface to call the contract function. `test2` uses call.

While testing on Remix, while calling `test1`, it consumed about 25161 gas. Calling `test2` it consumed about 25234 gas.

But when I decompile the runtime byte code, I can see how both functions are treated by the compiler:

Runtime bytecode: `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`

Decompiled here: https://ethervm.io/decompile

Decompiled `test1` function:

```js
function test1() {
        var var0 = storage[0x00] & 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
        var var1 = 0x24ccab8f;
        var temp0 = memory[0x40:0x60];
        memory[temp0:temp0 + 0x20] = (var1 & 0xffffffff) << 0xe0;
        var var2 = 0x01f3;
        var var3 = 0x01;
        var var4 = temp0 + 0x04;
        var2 = func_0451(var3, var4);
        var3 = 0x00;
        var4 = memory[0x40:0x60];
        var var5 = var2 - var4;
        var var6 = var4;
        var var7 = 0x00;
        var var8 = var0;
        var var9 = !address(var8).code.length;
    
        if (var9) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
    
        var temp1;
        temp1, memory[var4:var4 + var3] = address(var8).call.gas(msg.gas).value(var7)(memory[var6:var6 + var5]);
        var3 = !temp1;
    
        if (!var3) { return; }
    
        var temp2 = returndata.length;
        memory[0x00:0x00 + temp2] = returndata[0x00:0x00 + temp2];
        revert(memory[0x00:0x00 + returndata.length]);
    }
```

Decompiled `test2` function:

```js
function test2() {
        var var0 = 0x00;
        var var1 = var0;
        var var2 = storage[0x00] & 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
        var var3 = 0x00c4;
        var var4 = 0x7b;
        var var5 = memory[0x40:0x60] + 0x24;
        var3 = func_0356(var4, var5);
        var temp0 = memory[0x40:0x60];
        var temp1 = var3;
        memory[temp0:temp0 + 0x20] = temp1 - temp0 - 0x20;
        memory[0x40:0x60] = temp1;
        var temp2 = temp0 + 0x20;
        memory[temp2:temp2 + 0x20] = (memory[temp2:temp2 + 0x20] & 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff) | (~0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff & 0x24ccab8f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
        var3 = 0x014e;
        var5 = memory[0x40:0x60];
        var4 = temp0;
        var3 = func_03F5(var4, var5);
        var temp3 = memory[0x40:0x60];
        var temp4;
        temp4, memory[temp3:temp3 + 0x00] = address(var2).call.gas(msg.gas)(memory[temp3:temp3 + var3 - temp3]);
        var3 = returndata.length;
        var4 = var3;
    
        if (var4 == 0x00) { return; }
    
        var temp5 = memory[0x40:0x60];
        var3 = temp5;
        memory[0x40:0x60] = var3 + (returndata.length + 0x3f & ~0x1f);
        memory[var3:var3 + 0x20] = returndata.length;
        var temp6 = returndata.length;
        memory[var3 + 0x20:var3 + 0x20 + temp6] = returndata[0x00:0x00 + temp6];
    }
```

Notice how both are using `.call` anyways:

```js
address(var).call.gas(msg.gas).value(...)...
```

But it seems that `test1` is doing a little less work:

```js
address(var8).call.gas(msg.gas).value(var7)(memory[var6:var6 + var5]);
```

vs `test2`:

```js
address(var2).call.gas(msg.gas)(memory[temp3:temp3 + var3 - temp3]);
```

So, as we can see, in terms of performance they are almost the same, but it seems that using the interface is a little cheaper.

In general, using the interface is better because it is type safe. If you misspell the function name, it will not compile, like `IFACE(myContractAddress).fou("etc", 1)`. But if you use `.call` directly and misspell the function name, like `add.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("fou(string,uint256)", "call foo", 123)`, it will compile and run, and if the contract you are calling has a `fallback` function defined, then it will execute the `fallback` function, will revert otherwise.